# Raspbian Jessie (Debian 8) not displaying startup services and messages

Tags: raspbian, services, jessie-lite

I've setup a brand new SD card with **Raspbian Jessie Lite** (based on Debian 8).
Now I no longer see startup messages and the services notification ("[OK]", "[Failed]", etc.) when using service start/stop.

Looking for the problem with Google, I found a solution for Debian 8 Jessie that suggest to manage the `/etc/default/grub` file, but in my system there's no such file because I've no grub installed.

Solution for Debian: https://serverfault.com/questions/722389/debian-8-jessie-not-displaying-startup-services-and-messages

I'd like to restore, if possible, the same behaviour of Wheezy to see the messages. How can I do that on Jessie Lite?

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking about messages *at boot* or when you use `service foo start`?

Comment: @goldilocks The messages from services when you start/stop/restart them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I no longer see startup messages and the services notification ("[OK]", "[Failed]", etc.) when using service start/stop.

This is possibly because Debian/Raspbian changed the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) in version 8 from **SysV** to **systemd**;  `service` was really part of the former but remains for backward compatibility. If you want some informative and potentially colourful output after starting a service try:

```
systemctl status foo
```

Where `foo` is the service.  There's no color unless something is wrong or the service is persisent (e.g. `ssh`) and currently running.

> I found a solution for Debian 8 Jessie that suggest to manage the /etc/default/grub file

To explain about `grub`: It's a bootloader ("grand unified bootloader") but it is not used on the pi.  The only messages it would display would (normally) last a fraction of a second when the power is first turned on.

Comment: Yes, the new init system is the cause. But also using `systemctl start/stop servicename` syntax as you suggest, I've no message line under my command like "Starting service XXX... [OK]", etc.
Maybe it is because `systemd` runs process in background without blocking the console, so the messages are still there but in the background and so not visible...? Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: No, it just doesn't say anything if what you wanted worked.  If something goes wrong, then it will give you a message.